# Translating using multiple JSON for each language with ngx-translate

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I'm working on a project in Angular that needs to be translated for two languages: pt-br (my main language) and english. I managed to translate it with ngx-translate, but ngx uses a single file for each language, while in other applications related to this project we use the JHipster pattern (a directory for each language, with different JSON for each component).

What I want to do is use that same pattern for the translation of files in this particular project, but I've been met with limited luck so far. I tried both [Boris solution](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/199#issuecomment-339084987) and the [ngx-translate-multi-http-loader](https://github.com/denniske/ngx-translate-multi-http-loader), but they did not work for me.

Basically, while the multi-loader allows me something like this:

> assets/i18n/core/en.json

What I want to do is something like this:

> assets/i18n/en/core.json

Can anyone help me on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this, just a guess
`return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, "assets/i18n/", "/core.json");`

Comment: Holly molly, that worked! I tried it not really expecting it to work, but that actually worked!

Thank you so much, I've been trying to solve this for around a day, looking around and around, haha! I wish I could upvote you, but I can't, but thanks for the help, good sir!

Comment: It would be better if you would add some context to the answer

Answer (score 0):

I think other interesting approach would be using a webpack plugin which merge all your json files into only one json file in order to be read properly by the plugin an example (Based in Jhipster approach):

```
plugins: [
    //...other plugins
    new MergeJsonWebpackPlugin({
        output: {
            groupBy: [
                { pattern: "./src/main/webapp/i18n/es/*.json", fileName: "./i18n/es.json" },
                { pattern: "./src/main/webapp/i18n/en/*.json", fileName: "./i18n/en.json" }
                // jhipster-needle-i18n-language-webpack - JHipster will add/remove languages in this array
            ]
        }
    })
]
```